# rss is not updated immediately

Tags: python, rss, alert

I have a little script that monitors the RSS for 'new questions tagged with python' specifically on SO. It stores the feed in a variable on the first iteration of the loop, and then constantly checks the feed against the one stored in the variable. If the feed changes, it updates the variable and outputs the newest entry to the console, and plays a soundfile to alert me that there are new questions. All in all, it's quite handy as I don't have to keep an eye on anything. *However*, there are time discrepancies between new questions actually being posted, and my script detecting feed updates. These discrepancies seem to vary in the length of time, but generally, it's isn't instant and tends to not alert me before there has been enough action on a question so that it's been pretty much dealt with. Not always the case, but generally. **Is there a way for me to ensure much faster or quicker updates/alerts?** Or is this as good as it gets? (It's crossed my mind that this particular feed is only updated when there is actually action on a question.. anyone know if that's the case?)

Have I misunderstood the way that rss actually works?

```
import urllib2
import mp3play
import time
from xml.dom import minidom



def SO_notify():
    """ play alarm when rss is updated """

rss = ''
filename = "path_to_soundfile"
mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)
mp3.volume(25)

while True:  
    html = urllib2.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=python&sort=newest")
    new_rss = html.read()
    if new_rss == rss:
        continue
    rss = new_rss
    feed = minidom.parseString(rss)
    new_entry = feed.getElementsByTagName('entry')[0]
    title = new_entry.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    print title
    mp3.play()
    time.sleep(30) #Edit - thanks to all who suggested this

SO_notify()
```

Comment: Note that you don't have a sleep function by the looks of it. I'd say you're hammering SO and i'm not entirely convinced that it's appritiated, consider a `slee(30)` in there.

Comment: Also, API: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: @Torxed It's not entirely obvious to me how to use the api. Are those things I tag onto the end of a url, and must I use json?

Comment: yes you need to use `JSON`, since.. That's the way almost every API now days work. It's quite simple tho. `import json` and `json.loads(string)` :) The new API requires you to register a "application" which gives you a KEY and SECRET to work with. Next up you simply call for an URL with a set of parameters and headers, more so over here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions There's also Python libraries for this https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tree/updating-2.0

Comment: IMHO you should have a `sleep()` after every read so you don't hammer the server and change the logic so instead of reading the first entry, to read all entries until you get to the most recent in your DB (perform a sort of `diff`).

Comment: @LaurIvan I added a sleep to my code, as reflected in the question code.

Comment: @LaurIvan How might I perform a diff? While I know what you mean, is there a module for this?

Comment: @LaurIvan I came across difflib, going to have a look at that

Comment: @Totem: afaik, diff libraries perform full diffs on strings, which is not exactly what you need. You'd rather need to get the `id` text of each `entry` and check it against your most recent stored entry. You could use [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) to get a structured object for each entry.

Comment: If only StackOverflow supported PubSubHubbub again :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import requests
import mp3play
import time

curr_ids = []
filename = "path_to_soundfile"
mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)
mp3.volume(25)

while True:
    api_json = requests.get("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/unanswered?order=desc&tagged=python").json()
    new_questions = []
    all_questions = []
    for q in api_json["questions"]:
        all_questions.append(q["question_id"])
        if q["question_id"] not in curr_ids:
            new_questions.append(q["question_id"])
    if new_questions:
        print(new_questions)
        mp3.play()
    curr_ids = all_questions
    time.sleep(30)
```

Used the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package here because `urllib` gives me some encoding troubles.

Comment: This returns a list of question ids like: [21442125]

Comment: Yes, and if you replace `new_questions.append(q["question_id"])` with `new_questions.append(q["title"])` you have the titles. Open the SO api url in a browser to see what is available here.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you could have 2 solutions to this, depending on which approach you want:

1. Use JSON - this will give you a nice dict with all entries.
2. Use RSS (XML). In this case you'd need something like [feedparser](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html) to process your XML.

Either way, the code should be something like:

```
    # make curr_ids a dictionary for easier lookup
    curr_ids = []

    filename = "path_to_soundfile"
    mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)
    mp3.volume(25)

    # Loop
    while True:
        # Get the list of entries in objects
        entries = get_list_of_entries()

        new_ids = []

        for entry in entries:
            # Check if we reached the most recent entry
            if entry.id in curr_ids:
                # Force loop end if we did
                break

            new_ids.append(entry.id)

            # Do whatever operations
            print entry.title

        if len(new_ids) > 0:
           mp3.play()
           curr_ids = new_ids
        else:
           # No updates in the meantime
           pass

        sleep(30)
```

Several notes:

- I'd order the entries by "oldest" instead so the printed entries look like a stream, with the most recent one being the last printed out.
- the `new_ids` thing is to keep the list of ids to a minimum. Otherwise lookup will become slower with time
- `get_list_of_entries()` is a container to get the entries from the source (objects from XML or a dict from JSON). Depending on which approach you want, referring them is different (but the principle is the same)